# How to set output directory in context command?

Tags: context, context-mkiv

When using `lualatex` or `pdflatex` commands, there is an option to set the destination/processing folder as

```
lualatex -output-directory=/destination/folder file.tex
```

I was unable to find a similar option for `context` command. How to force `context` to write log files and resulting pdf in a custom folder?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
context filename --result=output-directory/filename
```

Comment: This is not identical to `-output-directory`, instead, it creates all files in the current directory and then move them to the output-directory. For example, rare but imagine, if a user does not have write permission for the current folder.

Comment: Yes, the options are not identical. ConTeXt always assumes that you have write permissions in `CWD`.

Comment: I get a `results are to be on the running path, not on 'output-directory', ignoring --result` error, anyone know why?

Answer (score 4):

Change the directory from which you invoke ConTeXt.

```
cd output-directory
context ../source-directory/file.tex
```

Comment: This will not work properly if you are relying on environment file being in parent or grant parent directories.

Comment: Also this needs `--path=../source-directory` if you **`\input`** any sources relative to `file.tex`.